# Php libchart with value from my custom table

Tags: 6, database

I want select value from my custom table where there are tweets saved.
I have the column for the counter of retweets and I want the sum of the count hourly for 24 hour.

I write this code:

```
$time = time();
$prev_date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $time);

$dataSet = new XYSeriesDataSet();

foreach($req as $val){
 $serie = new XYDataSet();
 $val_id = (int)substr((string)$val, 0, strpos((string)$val, "-")); 

    for($i=23; $i>=0; $i--){
        $next_date= date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $time - 3600*$i);
        $prev_date= date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $time - 3600*($i+1));
        $next_date = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($next_date));
        $prev_date = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($prev_date));
        /*$weight_q = db_query("SELECT SUM(`retweetCount` + `favoriteCount`)/2 as peso
                        FROM  `ax_twitter`
                        WHERE (`date` BETWEEN '{$prev_date}' AND '{$next_date}') AND (`ID_request` = %d)", $val_id);
        */
        $weight_q = db_query( "SELECT SUM(`retweetCount`) as peso FROM `ax_twitter` WHERE (`date` BETWEEN '$prev_date' AND '$next_date') AND (`ID_request` = %d)", $prev_date, $next_date, $val_id);

        while($row= db_fetch_object($weight_q)){
            echo($row->peso);
            $serie ->addPoint(new Point($next_date, $row->peso));
        }
        $prev_date = $next_date;
    }
$dataSet-> addSerie($val, $serie);

}
$chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

$chart->setTitle("Andamento dei Retweet e Favorite");
$chart->getPlot()->setGraphCaptionRatio(0.8);
$chart->render($path_image);    

}
```

I tried different ways with query sql but I have the following errors:

> warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '18:39:52 AND 01-10-2014 19:39:52) AND (`ID_request` = 1)' at line 1 query: SELECT SUM(`retweetCount`) as peso FROM `ax_twitter` WHERE (`date` BETWEEN 01-10-2014 18:39:52 AND 01-10-2014 19:39:52) AND (`ID_request` = 1) in trigger_error() (line 134 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\database.mysqli.inc). =>

When I added the quotes to the parameters of the sql query , however do not get any results for my graph. My question: is right way?...is right query?
With PHPAdmin I get right results if set two dates manually 
sorry for the language.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error msg, I think the code needs to be adapted, so that the current string (as it is now in the error message) like `BETWEEN 01-10-2014 18:39:52 AND 01-10-2014 19:39:52` is replaced by `BETWEEN "01-10-2014 18:39:52" AND "01-10-2014 19:39:52"`. So basically prepend and append a `"` to the variables $prev_date and $next_date ...

What isn't clear to me in this question though:

- What is that 'libchart' in the title of this question?
- What's the purpose of the $chart in your code? If it is because you're using [some charting module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985), it'd be interesting to know which module you're using, and you might want to add the **charts** tag to this question also ...